# Send 'POST' request without submit event

Tags: jquery, django

Event after which i am sending ajax is not submit. I even don't have sumbmin button. This is part of my jquery:

```
              var description_data = $('#description_form').serialize();
              alert(description_data)
              $.ajax({                  
                  url: '/accounts/profile/add_description/',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: description_data,
                  success: function(data){alert('ok')}
              });
```

and my view.py

```
def add_description(request):
    if request.is_ajax() or request.method == "POST":
        form = DescriptionForm(request.POST, prefix="description")
        if form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            profile = user.get_profile()                
            description = form.cleaned_data['content']
            profile.description=description
            profile.save()
            response = HttpResponse()
            response['Content-Type'] = "text/javascript"
            response.write(serializers.serialize('json', [profile], fields=('description')))
            return response
        else:
            return HttpResponse('form invalid')    
    else:
        return HttpResponse('error')
```

Ajas is sent not by submit event, but when it is send like that there `request.is_ajax() or request.method=="POST"` return False. How can i make it working?

Comment: didnt fully understood! you mean that in your add_description view request.is_ajax() is returning false?

Comment: I think, yes, because i have `if request.is_ajax() or request.method=="POST": .... else: return HttpResponse('error')` and i getting 'error'

Comment: please post your view method too!! thanks

Comment: have you verified for csrf with ajax?

Comment: looks good to me,  you sure you are getting 'error'  and not a 500?

Comment: Are you sure your ajax is hooked up right?  If you're not getting `request.is_ajax() == True` then I would suspect that the Form is being submitted the old-fashioned way.  (Hint: If you have a form of exactly one text field, the default behavior is to submit-on-enter.)

Comment: csrf is verified by middleware. i getting `error` on ajax `url` page, but when i am still on sending page i get 500. I have only one text field. What difference it makes? How to fix it?

Comment: just use fiddler to check your request.

Comment: for now i forget about this my function. too many problems, but maybe i will check it in fiddle one day. Thank You.

Comment: You probably need to call preventDefault, to stop the click event submitting the form before it runs the Ajax request.

$('#myButton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  //Your code from above
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to call preventDefault, to stop the click event submitting the form before it runs the Ajax request.

```
$('#myButton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  //Your code from above
});
```